# MainActivity not reading Subfolders Android Java

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an application that uses the Room, ViewModel approach. I created subfolders to organize my code as shown in the photo:
[image: MainActivity.Java]

How do I make my Main Activity recognize the code created in the subfolders? I tried invalidate caches/restart already and tried many times to rebuild the project.

Comment: Shift Files below `test` folder ex. `Customer`...... to main directory(where your other files are)

Comment: sorry i didnt quite get what you meant

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue when I created my folders. I used New->Folder->Java Folder when the right process should be New->Package

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an import statement for the classes to be recognized:

`import com.example.laundry.data.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel`

Comment: I did that but the ViewModel folder could not be identified by the system.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are various ways to solve this problem.
**Process 1**.
For your Adapter import this

```
import com.example.laundry.adapter.CustomerListAdapter;
```

For your ViewModel import this

```
import com.example.laundry.data.ViewModel.CustomerViewModel;
```

**Process 2**

If you write down your adapter/model class name it will show some popup. From there you can select.

[just like when I tried to import InfiniteScrollAdapter I got these options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHUfZ.png)

**Process 3**
Please check if you have already import that adapter/model class with the different package names. Just delete that line and import again with alt+ enter

Comment: There was an issue when I created my folders. I used New->Folder->Java Folder when the right process should be New->Package. I did all the steps you did and the new folders could not be scanned. So I created a new project and created a new package instead of a new java folder and it works now